# Display array from php using html form checkbox

Tags: php, html, forms, web-services, post

I have a form of checkboxes as shown below:

```
<form method="POST" action="display.php">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="options[]"> 
    <span class="checkboxText"> Fruits</span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="options[]"> 
    <span class="checkboxText">Vegetables </span><br><br>
    <button class="button" type="submit" value="display">DISPLAY</button>
</form>
```

I get the `options[]` using `$_POST['options']` and save the array of data in a variable. I want to display the array of fruits if the fruits checkbox is checked, the vegetables array if vegetables checkbox is checked and display both of them if both are checked and display a message saying "Fruits and Vegetables are healthy". This is the php code I have so far but it does not seem to work as I would like it to.

```
<?php
    $values = $_POST['options'];
    $n = count($values);
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++ )
    {
        if($values[$i] === "1"  && $values[$i] == "2")
        {
            //iteration to display both tables
            echo 'Fruits and Vegetables are healthy';
        }           
        else if($values[$i] === "1")
        {
            //display fruits
        }
        else if( $values[$i] == "2")
        {
            //display vegetables        
        }       
    }
?>
```

The problem with my php code is that is does not go into the first if at all. It just displays both tables from the other two ifs (since the echo is not displayed either). Is there any way I could solve this?

Comment: `$values[$i]` pulls a single value from the array, it can never be both "1" and "2" at the same time.

Comment: but it takes both values when I check them both. Isn't that supposed to give it both the values when I use the for loop?

Comment: also, could you suggest me a solution if possible?

Comment: You only one value *per* traversal through the  loop. Add an `echo "index:" . $i . " value:" + $values[$i]` to visualize this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a loop for this. You just need to check in `$_POST['options']` for each of the values in question. I would suggest using the text you want to display as the values for your checkboxes so you don't have to convert from numbers to words.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Fruits" name="options[]">
<span class="checkboxText"> Fruits</span>
<input type="checkbox" value="Vegetables" name="options[]">
<span class="checkboxText">Vegetables </span><br><br>
```

Then for the display, just output the fruits/vegetables arrays depending on whether or not those values are present in `$_POST['options']`.

```
if (!empty($_POST['options'])) {

    echo implode(' and ', $_POST['options']) . " are healthy";

    if (in_array('Fruits', $_POST['options'])) {
        // show the fruits
    }

    if (in_array('Vegetables', $_POST['options'])) {
        // show the veg
    }
}
```

Comment: Only problem with words as the value is if that value is then used as an id for a db call to get the list of fruits and or vege ..... hard to tell from the original example though. If using numbers `if(in_array("1", $_POST['options']) &&in_array("2", $_POST['options']))` could be used for the echo

Comment: @JonP it's true, if the numbers are going to be used for something else we certainly wouldn't want to change them into words like this. But the idea is the same even if we stick with numbers. Just look in the array for each one, no need to loop.

Comment: Just tried the solution you gave me and it worked. Thank you.